# Protractor testing full flow

Tags: angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing

I have 2 AngularJS SPAs:

- first (USER_APP) allows user to submit "tasks"
- second (ADMIN_APP) allows admin look through the list of tasks, and complete

The complete flow is the following:

1) admin sees empty queue in ADMIN_APP

2) user creates task in USER_APP

3) user sees 'status' screen in USER_APP with countdown ("Left 5..1 min to complete")

4) admin sees task in queue and completes it

5) user sees 'result' screen in USER_APP

6) Go to 1

So I order to organize e2e of this flow with Protractor I see two variants:

1. Do all the stuff with protractor: the problem here is that apps are in different projects, I need advise how to run Protractor e2e that spans multiple Angular apps
2. Perform steps for "other side" with API. I.e. when I test USER_APP, then steps 1,4 are performed via API REST calls, when I test ADMIN_APP steps 2,3,5 are performed using API. The pros: is that e2e for each app resides in app's project, the cons are that: it is 'not real e2e'. Plus is there any extension for protractor for making API calls?
3. Use another solution??